# Boosting in unsupervised learning - methods and use cases

Tags: unsupervised-learning, boosting, ensemble-learning

I'm looking for methods and uses cases for applying [boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)) or other [ensemble methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) for [unsupervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning)

Examples of such methods and use cases are:

1. [Boosting density estimation](http://genie.weizmann.ac.il/pubs/conference/nips02.pdf) Saharon Rosset & Eran Segal use boosting for [density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation)
2. [Self supervised boosting](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2275-self-supervised-boosting.pdf) Max Welling, Richard S. Zemel, and Geoffrey E. Hinton use boosting for [feature extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction)
3. [Toward an Unsupervised Boosting-Like Approach](http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~lallich/Articles/Conf_Internat/08_BSL_SFC_CLADAG_boostclustering.pdf) Romain Billot, Henri-Maxime Suchier and Stephane Lallich use boosting for [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)

Another related case appears at [Text Categorization based on Boosting Association Rules](http://isoft.postech.ac.kr/publication/iconf/icsc08_yoon.pdf) by Yongwook Yoon & Gary G. Lee.
They use boosting on association rules that are used for classification (supervised). The association rules themselves were given to the boosting algorithm and there was no use of boosting to generate the association rules (unsupervised).

Comment: Thanks for the interesting list. Please update if you end up finding more examples.